# Popup displaying automatically - javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, textbox, web

I'd like to make the box which  comes up automatically on my website that recommended browser to browse this website is Google Chrome. I'm not really sure about the code, i know it has to be done in javascript. I'd like it to be in this type of format - of the alert:

```
<script>
 function myFunction()
 {
 alert("I am an alert box!");
 }
 </script>
```

Comment: so whats the problem?

Comment: <script>

 alert("Better to view this site on Google Chrome Browser");
 
 </script>

Comment: It worth spending the time to make it ok in any browser if you do not use some cutting edge html or script not available in other browsers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Omit the 1st, 2nd and 4th line. Just `alert("some text")` within `<script></script>` will do. But honestly, if you use elements on your website that depend on a specific browser, you're making a big mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Try this
Script

```
function myFunction()
 {
 alert("Browse Using Google Chrome Browser!");
 }
 window.onload=myFunction;
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/WwvCP/3/)

Comment: Please do not use inline onload when you have window.onload

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
 function myFunction()
 {
  alert("I am an alert box!");
 }
</script>
```

`myFunction();`

This will work.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
window.onload = function () {
// do stuff here
}
```